# Calculate number of specific type each author created in a specific folder

Tags: git

For example, when I need to calculate number of .py files that was created (author, not committer) by each author in a specific folder of git repository? Is there anyway to archive it?

 Thank you.

Comment: How do you figure out who the author is if it's not the committer?

Comment: as i understand, when a dev created a file, he's author of that file

Comment: yeah, so that would be some sort of file system property and not something that git persists. Git's concept of 'author' is the same as 'committer'. I don't think you're going to get this to work with native git.